# Transclude inside ng-repeat, controller function incorrect transclude param

Tags: angularjs

I created directive that appends transclude value after the directive body. I cant use ng-transclude inside my directive because it creates  for the simple text as transclude value and it break my page. I use

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $transclude) {
     $element.append($transclude().contents());           
}
```

to append it. It works great, but when I use my directive inside ng-repeat something goes wrong and $transclude().contents() don't contain my text. Can someone explain this behavior?

Here example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/1y4avkwmgjhiKkuoZlug

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why $transclude().contents() don't contain your text, but I can show how to easy fix that please code below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('test', function(){
  
  return {
    transclude: true,
   
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div >From directive </div> <div ng-transclude></div><hr/>',
            
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="a in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
    <test>From transclude {{a}}</test>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Did you see, that transcluded text wrapped with

    `<div ng-transclude="">
        <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">From transclude 1</span>
    </div>`

It can break page in some cases.